# NodeJS XMLHttpRequest response

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I'm making and app and I need do get the number of verses of a chapter of the bible.
I'm getting the info from http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/
In order to do that I am making an XMLHttpRequest to send to the server from the function `getVerses()` from the site.
The problem that I am facing is that I'm not getting a .responseText from the XMLHttpRequest. When I use firebug and call that function, in the Network tab > Response tab I get nothing but on Network tab > Preview I get the answer.
Where is this answer coming from and what is the variable that has this value?

My node code is as follows:

```
let XMLHttpRequest2 = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

function getVerses() {
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest2(); //: new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == xmlhttp.DONE ) {
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
            else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) { }
            else { }
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/ajax.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send('callFunc=getMaxVerseForChapter&book='+'"Genesis"'+'&chapter='+'"2"');
}

getVerses();
```

Comment: nevermind ... nodejs wont have a problem with CORS

Comment: `Network tab > Response tab` ... hang on ... is this nodejs or not?

Comment: your problem is `'callFunc=getMaxVerseForChapter&book='+'"Genesis"'+'&chapter='+'"2"'` ... change that to `'callFunc=getMaxVerseForChapter&book='+'Genesis'+'&chapter='+'2'` - in other words get rid of the `"` around the book and chapter values

Comment: more simply - `'callFunc=getMaxVerseForChapter&book=Genesis&chapter=2'` for the hard coded data

Comment: thank you for your answer @JaromandaX but it still doesn't print the answer.

Comment: In Firefox Firebug tabs that I mention you can see how the answer is returned, that's why I told you to see these tabs. You should experiment first in the browser to see that in the Response tab it doesn't show nothing but on the preview it shows a number. Something is not right, check for yourself

Comment: firefox firebug ... what does this have to do with node? I'm confused ... are you using a node server to get the request for the browser?

Comment: @JaromandaX no i'm not using a node server. the node program that I have acts as a client, not server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the server is very strict and it expects the header to be called `Content-Type` and not `Content-type`. Some kind of poorly written stuff obviously (in PHP). Also get rid of the double quotes around the values you are sending.

Here you go:

```
let XMLHttpRequest2 = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

function getVerses() {
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest2(); //: new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == xmlhttp.DONE ) {
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
            else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) { }
            else { }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/ajax.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send('callFunc=getMaxVerseForChapter&book=' + 'Genesis' + '&chapter=' + '2');
}

getVerses();
```

and since you are hardcoding the values, you don't really need string concatenation:

```
xmlhttp.send('callFunc=getMaxVerseForChapter&book=Genesis&chapter=2);
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you